# Github global default issue templates not working

Tags: github, github-issues

I followed the documentation in https://help.github.com/en/github/building-a-strong-community/creating-a-default-community-health-file to create a default community health file. Namely issue templates.

I created a new public repository, named it ".github", added an "ISSUE_TEMPLATE" folder and in it a "bug_report.md" with a content that is copied from another repo of mine that has the same template defined.

However when I try to open an issue in another repository that DOESN'T have any templates defined, the bug template is not available.

I also tried going to the "Settings" of said ".github" repository and adding a "feature" template from the provided Github functionality (Features section, issue templates). That created a the folder ".github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE" with the file "feature_request.md" inside it. To make clear, this means I have a repo, named ".github" with a separate ".github" folder inside it (and the folder "ISSUE_TEMPLATE" inside that folder).

But that also doesn't work. I tested both by going to another repo of mine and trying to open a new issue - no templates, whatsoever provided and by creating a whole new repo with no files in it, apart from a readme.

What am I doing wrong? According to Github I should be able to define issue templates that will be used in all my repos that don't define their own. I made sure all my repos are under the same account.